# Return JSON Appcelerator Cloud Services

Tags: ios, xcode, appcelerator

I using this code for get Json for Custom Object in ACS (Appcelerator Cloud Services) using Cocoa SDK https://github.com/cocoafish/cocoafish-ios-sdk

```
if ([response.meta.methodName isEqualToString:@"showObjects"]) {
  NSArray *institucional = [response.response objectForKey:@"Institucional"];
  NSString *strinstitucional  = [institucional objectAtIndex:0];
}
```

My problem is that NSString strinstitucional the JSON comes invalid. He change : for = and remove quotes for some parameters. Is this correct?

I'm noob for Objective

Tks!